How do I insert all data in one row and insert users input as a multiplier in my sql query?
Everytime I try to insert data into my database, this error occurs right at the first statement:
I get an internal server error and cannot insert all values in one row.
My code is:
c=request.form.get("c")
d=int(request.form.get("a"))
    db.execute("INSERT INTO table (a) VALUES (?), session["user_id"]
    db.execute ("INSERT INTO table (b) SELECT DISTINCT volume *:multiplier FROM A WhHERE type= :c", multiplier=d)

They are followed by more similar statements.
However, the valiable c in the sql statement is not connected to the c variable I declared above.
I want to import those values into an other table. But I only get 0 as a result.
The table of the database is :
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "table" (
    "a" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "b" INTEGER NOT NULL,
...
    UNIQUE(a,b,...)
    PRIMARY KEY("a")
);

Could anyone give me a hint or tell me how I could do all of the statements in one?

Your code seems to be incomplete.

This question is similar to: SQLite3 database or disk is full / the database disk image is malformed. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Schwern I tried to repair my database, but it does not insert the values in one row in the table. Instead I get one value in a column in a row, but the rest is "NONE".

@user40089 Your posted code has syntax errors. We can't help you until you show us code which demonstrates the problem. We also need to know your table schemas, sample data, and your expected results. Finally, it could just be a corrupted database. Please be careful to make sure your question is accurate and contains all the necessary information.

Are you using Flask-SQLAlchemy? If so, what version?

@GordThompson I use SQLite 3.46.0

I figured out, that the second insert sql query results in an unsuppported value ("volume *1) when the multiplier is 1. But I want to get an integer. The volume is supposed to be a numeric value in the row where type=c. I do not know what I am doing wrong.
